# VB.NET DataGridView cambiar estilo imagen (tile, stretch, center, zoom)

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, datagrid

Como puedo cambiar en una Picture Cell de un DataGridView, que la imagen se vea en modo tile, stretch, center o zoom?

Por defecto me sale la imagen que sobresale del Cell y necesito que se vea entera.

Comment: en wpf o winforms?

Comment: Saludos gbianchi, en Windows Forms!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es modificar la propiedad `ImageLayout` de la columna para que sea de tipo `Stretch`:

```
CType(dataGridView1.Columns("imagen"), DataGridViewImageColumn).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
```

Cambia `"imagen"` por el nombre de tu columna.

Comment: En vb.net como sería? disculpa la ignorancia..

Comment: @AdrianHernandoSolanas perdona, se me escapó que era vb.net. Prueba con la respuesta editada

Comment: Muchas gracias ya funciona!